# Mysql change column collation and character set of information schema

Tags: mysql, database, system, collation

I want to change column collation and character set of system database information_schema...

Can anyone give any input on how to do this?  Is there any special priviledges i need for this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot run `ALTER TABLE` commands on the tables in `information_schema`. Instead you will probably want to take a look at the `character_set_*` variabes. You can see which variables are set to which values in your MySQL server with a `show variables` command:

```
show variables like "character_set_%";
```

The variable that has to do with meta data in MySQL, such as the `information_schema` tables, is the `character_set_system` variable. I think the `my.cnf` is the right place to set it.

There's more information on this page: [UTF-8 for Metadata](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-metadata.html).

For ordinary tables, you change the character set of a table with an `ALTER TABLE` command:

```
alter table some_table convert to character set utf8;
```

To do this, you will need the "alter" privilege.

You can see which privileges your MySQL server supports with a `show privileges` command, and you can see which privileges are granted to your current user with a `show grants` command.

Answer (score 19):

To change the character set and collation for all columns in an existing table, use:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name [COLLATE collation_name];
```

Comment: what priviledges do i need to to alter system database any idea

Comment: @MySQLDBA you will need the "alter" privilege, see Christian answer

Comment: Make sure you consider this warning before executing an `ALTER` command 
> If you use ALTER TABLE to convert a column from one character set to another, 
> MySQL attempts to map the data values, but if the character sets are incompatible, there may be data loss.

[MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-column.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
alter table some_table convert to character set utf8;
```

awesome that worked great as far as i can tell for me, now i can use chinese in that tables!! and i can remove all the utf8_encode() utf8_decode() throughout my site!