# Generating a kind of intelligent news Excerpts

Tags: php, xhtml, ascii

I have developed a news portal website (in French):

http://www.monde-presse.com

I'm encountring small issues with the headlines.
I'm taking the first 64 chars and adding "..." at the end.

My issue is in database the "é" becomes "Ã©" and some descriptions having the 64th char as "Ã", so I got an unknown char symbol!! It's embarassing.

Is there any php function that can handle this? My idea is that I can take less than 64 chars but not more. So if the 64th char is wild like "Ã" the php try to take 63 if the same, 62 and so on.

Comment: Please go back to your old questions and accept some of the valid answers. People will be more inclined to help you then.

Comment: Ok, done, now you are blacklisting me with your comment. please remove it and let people help me. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on what database you are using, you need to change the Charset to be UTF-8, chances are it was defaulted to Latin.

This can be done in phpMyAdmin, if you have that installed, or with an alter statement.

**Resources if MySQL**

[MySQL Change Column Collation and Character Set of Information Schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979656/mysql-change-column-collation-and-character-set-of-information-schema/992889#992889)

Comment: Thank you Brad F Jacobs, this is my best answer