# JSON output using Express using Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I have Created a database in mysql

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test456;
+-----+-------+-------------------------+
| _id | name  | image                   |
+-----+-------+-------------------------+
|   1 | Chris | /home/images/index.jpeg |
+-----+-------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

and **My Express program is below**

```
var express = require('express')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql'); // <---- HERE

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: "root",
    database: 'test123'
});

connection.connect(); // <---- AND HERE

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 7005);


app.get('/',function(request,response){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM test456', function(err, rows, fields)

   {
            console.log('Connection result error '+err);
            console.log('no of records is '+rows.length);
                    response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            response.end(JSON.stringify(rows));
    });

} );



http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**Output::**

```
[{"_id":1,"name":"Chris","image":[47,104,111,109,101,47,105,109,97,103,101,115,47,105,110,100,101,120,46,106,112,101,103]}]
```

Clearly you can see that i am not able to generate the image url instead i am generating hexadecimal number ...... how to make the hexadecimal number to a url

My research shows that i need to use base64 encoding 
but how can i apply that here

any ideas

Answer (score 1):

The output is probably because each `image` is a [`Buffer`](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) rather than a `String`.

```
console.log(Buffer.isBuffer(rows[0].image)); // true
```

You may need to [alter the character set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979656/mysql-change-column-collation-and-character-set-of-information-schema) in MySQL to UTF-8 for compatibility with Node.js:

```sql
ALTER TABLE test456 CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

But, you can also specify a [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) with `JSON.stringify()`:

```
response.end(JSON.stringify(rows, function (key, value) {
    if (Buffer.isBuffer(value)) {
        return value.toString();
    } else {
        return value;
    }
}));
```